# Computer freezes when compiling flutter program

Tags: flutter, gradle

Whenever i try to compile my flutter code gradle uses up all of my ram and freezes my computer.

Comment: Check if you are connected to internet. what are your system specifications?

Comment: If your system is slow and you are using Android Studio then do consider using VScode instead. Also, if possible use your Mobile phone in place of Emulator to run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem, try `flutter clean`